# How to check of the user input value is Upper case, Lower case or a digit using Shell Script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a `shell script` to read user input data and check if the input value is either **Upper Case, Lower Case or anything else**. But what I wrote is only checking a **single character**

Here is what I wrote:

```
printf 'Please enter a character: '
IFS= read -r c
case $c in
  ([[:lower:]]) echo lowercase letter;;
  ([[:upper:]]) echo uppercase letter;;
  ([[:alpha:]]) echo neither lower nor uppercase letter;;
  ([[:digit:]]) echo decimal digit;;
  (?) echo any other single character;;
  ("") echo nothing;;
  (*) echo anything else;;
esac
```

**How can I make it read a long String other than a single character and get the output accordingly?**

Comment: `Upper Case, Lower Case or anything else` - this means it can be anything. You have to use regex-aware tool, like `grep` `sed` `awk` or bash `[[` comparision. The internet is full of examples, [grep example](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/grep-command-in-unix/).

Comment: I am new to this script shell and can you give an example please?

Comment: Please include input and output examples in your question

Comment: `input: Hello World` ==> `Out put: anything`

Comment: So you want to know if the whole sentence is in uppercase or lowercase, not only the first word, right?

Comment: @RigaCrypto whole sentence

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways, here you have one:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter something: "  str
echo "Your input is: $str"

strUppercase=$(printf '%s\n' "$str" | awk '{ print toupper($0) }')
strLowercase=$(printf '%s\n' "$str" | awk '{ print tolower($0) }')

if [ -z "${str//[0-9]}" ]
then
    echo "Digit"
elif [ $str == $strLowercase ]
then
    echo "Lowercase"
elif [ $str == $strUppercase ]
then
    echo "Uppercase"
else
    echo "Something else"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Preceding your use with `shopt -s extglob`, you can use `+([[:upper:]])` to match a string composed of one or more uppercase letters.

From `man 1 bash`:

```
       If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several
       extended  pattern  matching operators are recognized.  In the following
       description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated
       by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the fol‐
       lowing sub-patterns:

              ?(pattern-list)
                     Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
              *(pattern-list)
                     Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
              +(pattern-list)
                     Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
              @(pattern-list)
                     Matches one of the given patterns
              !(pattern-list)
                     Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

Use, for example, `+([[:upper:][:digit:] .])` to match one or more {uppercase letters, digits, spaces, dots}. Consider using some of the other *following classes defined in the POSIX standard:

`alnum`  `alpha`  `ascii`  `blank`  `cntrl` `digit` `graph` `lower` `print` `punct` `space` `upper` `word` `xdigit`*

Proof (just a test on an example) that it works:

```sh
shopt -s extglob; case "1A5. .Q7." in (+([[:upper:][:digit:] .])) echo "it works";; esac
```